# Using ARKit, loading of 3D object is not anchored to the specific latitude longitude location

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, aranchor

I tried Apple ARGeotracking for loading 3D model which is of a house.I provided the latitude and the longitude location so as to load the object at that specific location. But the object is not anchored to the specific lat long location. Also the object tends to move as the user moves.

code for horizontal surface detection

```
 // Create a new AR Scene View.
        sceneView = ARSCNView(frame: view.bounds)
        sceneView.delegate = self
        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        view.addSubview(sceneView)
  
        //configure scene view session to detect horizontal planes
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
        
        //uncomment to see feature points
        sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]
```

// Responds to a user tap on the AR view.

```
 @objc
    func handleTapOnARView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     
        addGeoAnchor(at: projectLocation2D)

    }
```

Adding ARGeoAnchor and providing latitude location location in params

//MARK:- ADD GEOANCHOR

```
func addGeoAnchor(at location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, altitude: CLLocationDistance? = nil) {
    var geoAnchor: ARGeoAnchor!
    if let altitude = altitude {
        geoAnchor = ARGeoAnchor(coordinate: location, altitude: altitude)
    } else {
        geoAnchor = ARGeoAnchor(coordinate: location)
    }
    addGeoAnchor(geoAnchor)
}


func addGeoAnchor(_ geoAnchor: ARGeoAnchor) {
    
    // Don't add a geo anchor if Core Location isn't sure yet where the user is.
    guard isGeoTrackingLocalized else {
        alertUser(withTitle: "Cannot add geo anchor", message: "Unable to add geo anchor because geo tracking has not yet localized.")
        return
    }
    arView.session.add(anchor: geoAnchor)
}



var isGeoTrackingLocalized: Bool {
    if let status = arView.session.currentFrame?.geoTrackingStatus, status.state == .localized {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func distanceFromDevice(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Double {
    if let devicePosition = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
        return MKMapPoint(coordinate).distance(to: MKMapPoint(devicePosition))
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

// MARK: - ARSessionDelegate
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    for geoAnchor in anchors.compactMap({ $0 as? ARGeoAnchor }) {
        // Effect a spatial-based delay to avoid blocking the main thread.
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + (distanceFromDevice(geoAnchor.coordinate) / 10)) {
            // Add an AR placemark visualization for the geo anchor.
            self.arView.scene.addAnchor(Entity.placemarkEntity(for: geoAnchor))
        }
        
        // Add a visualization for the geo anchor in the map view.
        let anchorIndicator = AnchorIndicator(center: geoAnchor.coordinate)

        // Remember the geo anchor we just added
        let anchorInfo = GeoAnchorWithAssociatedData(geoAnchor: geoAnchor, mapOverlay: anchorIndicator)
        self.geoAnchors.append(anchorInfo)
    }
}
```

didAdd anchor method is called and here I have provided the url to load the model as I was using EchoAR sdk to load model into our app. The models loads but it is not anchored to the specific geographic location.Here the value of modelURL is coming fro echoAR sdk that I have used. It return model in .usdz format.

```
extension Entity {
    static func placemarkEntity(for arAnchor: ARAnchor) -> AnchorEntity {
        let placemarkAnchor = AnchorEntity(anchor: arAnchor)
        if modelURL != nil{
        let entity = (try? Entity.load(contentsOf: modelURL!))!
        placemarkAnchor.addChild(entity)
        }
        else{
            Utilities.sharedInstance.showError(message: "8C. ===Unable to render AR Model===")

        }
        return placemarkAnchor
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code inline using code blocks (```code```)? It's very hard to follow your question when there are so many links to click.

Comment: @fruitcoder, I have edited my question. Have a look and help me to fix it please.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.